# Startup class: how to add scoped service and middleware

Tags: c#, scope, integration-testing, startup

I am trying to add correlationid to request, and track them everywhere.

I have the following lines in the startup class:

```
services.AddScoped<ICorrelationIdGenerator, CorrelationIdGenerator>();
// ... other code
app.AddCorrelationIdMiddleware();
```

Then I have the following:

```
public class CorrelationIdGenerator : ICorrelationIdGenerator
{
    private string _correlationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public string Get() => _correlationId;

    public void Set(string correlationId)
    {
        _correlationId = correlationId;
    }
}
```

```
public static IApplicationBuilder AddCorrelationIdMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
        => applicationBuilder.UseMiddleware<CorrelationIdMiddleware>();
```

```
public class CorrelationIdMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CorrelationIdMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, ICorrelationIdGenerator correlationIdGenerator)
    {
        var correlationId = GetCorrelationId(context, correlationIdGenerator);
        AddCorrelationIdHeaderToResponse(context, correlationId);

        await _next(context);
    }

    private static StringValues GetCorrelationId(HttpContext context, ICorrelationIdGenerator correlationIdGenerator)
    {
        if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(HttpHeaderConstants.CORRELATIONID, out var correlationId))
        {
            correlationIdGenerator.Set(correlationId);
            return correlationId;
        }
        else
        {
            return correlationIdGenerator.Get();
        }
    }

    private static void AddCorrelationIdHeaderToResponse(HttpContext context, StringValues correlationId)
    {
        context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add(HttpHeaderConstants.CORRELATIONID, new[] { correlationId.ToString() });
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is mainly that is breaking existing tests and I have no idea how to fix them. The tests inherit from `IntegrationTestBase<Startup>`.

I added the following line to the `IntegrationTestBase<Startup>`:

```
services.AddScoped<ICorrelationIdGenerator, CorrelationIdGenerator>();
```

and I was expecting it to work.

Instead I got a bunch of errors that were not before the added functionality and

> Cannot consume scoped service

from singleton x. Which x is the database that has nothing to do with the new functionality.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to inject a scoped service into a singleton service? How would the DI manage that?

Comment: what do you mean by DI?

Comment: Dependency Injection - the process that actually constructs the services based on the registrations.

Comment: Look at it this way: you have a singleton service (only created once) and you're trying to inject a scoped service (lives only for the lifetime of the request) into it. This isn't possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Stuartd has said in his comments, what I was trying to do was not possible due to their live times.

Solution: changed the singleton to be injected

Answer (score 1):

Although your question has been answered, regarding correlation id let me suggest an alternative solution.

In one of my earlier projects we used the following Nuget package:

https://github.com/stevejgordon/CorrelationId

It is highly configurable.
It is even able to forward the correlation id to `HttpClient` calls.
Whenever you need the correlation id then just inject `ICorrelationContextAccessor`.